# Enviar a imprimir pero no la vista actual

Tags: javascript, print

Estoy trabajando en una vista y necesita enviar a imprimir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que quiero enviar a imprimir, pero no la tabla completa, si no un formato específico

```
Salón de fiesta por Gabriel Ramírez (Cerrada)
Hospital español por Ericka Buendia (Cerrada)
Hospital español por Ericka Buendia (Cancelada)
```

Me gustaría que se imprimiera sólo esa información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El clásico `window.print()` me imprime toda la pantalla (Hasta cosas fuera de la tabla)
¿Qué me recomiendan usar?

Answer (score 1):

Esto sirve?

```js
function Imprimir(_div) {
   var contenido= document.getElementById(_div).innerHTML;
   var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
   window.print();
   document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}
```

```css
#areaImprimir {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div id="areaImprimir">
      <h3><center>Imprimir</center></h3>
</div>

<p><center>No imprimir</center></p>
<p><center>No imprimir</center></p>
<p><center>No imprimir</center></p>

<input type="button" onclick="Imprimir('areaImprimir')" value="imprimir div" />
```